# Html layout - prevent elements from re-sizing

Tags: html, css

I want make a html page that has div's that take up a certain percentage (width and height) and that its elements inside do not resize when I resize the window, is this possible?

Example:

```
/* CSS */

#left-content-area {
    position: fixed,
    width: 19%,
    height: 60%,
    left: 27%,
    top: 20%
}

<!-- Html -->

<div id="left-content-area">
    First name: <input type="text" id=first_name_id" style="width=90%">
    Last name: <input type="text" id=last_name_id" style="width=90%">
    Phone number: <input type="text" id=phone_number_id" style="width=90%">
    Address: <input type="text" id=address_id" style="width=90%">
    <!--
    And more....
    -->
</div>
```

Do I have to hard-wire it to pixels instead to prevent the input fields from re-sizing?

Comment: style="width=90%"> should be style="width: 90%">

Comment: This makes no sense at all. The entire point of using percentages is so that things to resize when the window size changes. (Every single one of your CSS rules has a syntax error in it BTW).

Comment: Doesn't sizing by percentage inherently mean that you want the elements' size to be based on the size of the window? Quentin beat me to saying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't give percentage to elements.

You can use pixel, em, rem.

If you want to "play" a bit like give a min value and then scale with percentage you can still use for example width (percentage) and min-width (pixels)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width

Also I suggest you to avoid using inline style if not necessary.

Just add a class to all the input you want to look the same

```
.class {
    width:90%;
    min-width:100px;
}
```

Comment: It works - good enough - to add a minimumd width in pixels. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must have width written in a non-dynamic unit like `px` to make sure that resizing the parent element does not affect the width of the child element.

```
#left-content-area {
    position: fixed;
    width: 19%;
    height: 60%;
    left: 27%;
    top: 20%;
    min-width: 150px;
}
#left-content-area input{
    width:140px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So I believe I got it to work. There were a few errors. I changed your commas to semi-colons in the CSS and changed your = to : in the style tag of each input type.

```
/* CSS */

#left-content-area {
    position: fixed;
    width: 19%;
    height: 60%;
    left: 27%;
    top: 20%
}

/* HTML */

<div id="left-content-area">
    First name: <input type="text" id=first_name_id" style="width: 90%">
    Last name: <input type="text" id=last_name_id" style="width: 90%">
    Phone number: <input type="text" id=phone_number_id" style="width: 90%">
    Address: <input type="text" id=address_id" style="width: 90%">
<!--
And more....
-->
</div>
```

Let me know if this works! Thanks